# Losing data when I use Pandas Resample

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I apologize if I am doing something wrong but I have tried a long time to get this on my own. I have a huge dataset with all historical prices (daily closes) for about 3000 stocks which equates to over 15 mil rows. The problem is I can't seem to resample the data without losing a lot of the data. My goal is to keep Monthly closes ONLY for all Stocks while maintaining the shape of the data including the ticker, date, and close columns.

```
wiki_prices_df = pd.read_csv('/gitHub/finance/PRICES_03_11_18.csv',usecols=['ticker','date','close'],parse_dates=['date'])

wiki_prices_df[:10]
    ticker  date    close
0   A   1999-11-18  44.00
1   A   1999-11-19  40.38
2   A   1999-11-22  44.00
3   A   1999-11-23  40.25
4   A   1999-11-24  41.06
5   A   1999-11-26  41.19
6   A   1999-11-29  42.13
7   A   1999-11-30  42.19
8   A   1999-12-01  42.94
9   A   1999-12-02  44.13

wiki_prices_df.shape
(15360208, 3)
```

The 'date' column has already been set to a Timestamp data.  I am getting mixed results and not sure which or how I should use "date_range" or ".resample" to reduce the amount of rows to just the Month Ending.  I have tried this

```
wiki_prices_df_monthly = wiki_prices_df.resample('M', on='date')
wiki_prices_df_monthly.shape
print(type(wiki_prices_df_monthly))

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: FutureWarning: 
.resample() is now a deferred operation
You called shape(...) on this deferred object which materialized it into a dataframe
by implicitly taking the mean.  Use .resample(...).mean() instead

<class 'pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler'>
```

Comment: Please post sample of undesired results to avoid ambiguity of *I am getting mixed results*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is filtering, not re-sampling.

```
wiki_prices_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(wiki_prices_df["date"])
wiki_prices_df = wiki_prices_df[wiki_prices_df["date"].dt.is_month_end]
```

Would remove everything but the end of month rows.